# Further problems with counting occurrences of strings in an Array

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am copying a question and answer from elsewhere as it partly goes into what I need but not completely.

In ASP classic, is there a way to count the number of times a string appears in an array of strings and output them based on string and occurrence count?

For example if I have an array which contains the following :

```
hello
happy
hello
hello
testing
hello
test
happy
```

The output would be:

```
hello 4
happy 2
test 1
testing 1
```

The answer that was given was this:

I'm assuming the language is VBScript (since that's what most people use with classic ASP).

You can use a Dictionary object to keep track of the individual counts:

```
Function CountValues(pArray)
    Dim i, item
    Dim dictCounts
    Set dictCounts = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(pArray) To UBound(pArray)
        item = pArray(i)
        If Not dictCounts.Exists(item) Then 
            dictCounts.Add item, 0
        End If
        dictCounts.Item(item) = dictCounts.Item(item) + 1
    Next
    Set CountValues = dictCounts
End Function
```

This is great but I can't work out how to grab the top 2 most used words, display them and be able to put them in their own variable for use elsewhere.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the dictionary object using [this method](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/dictionary_keys.html). Inside that loop keep track of the top two keys and their counts in either a new array or two new variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a Dictionary object in VBScript, so you have to use something else.

My advice is using a disconnected Recordset object to hold the items and their occurrences. Such object natively support sorting and it's pretty easy to use. To achieve this have such function instead:

```
Function CountValues_Recordset(pArray)
    Dim i, item
    Dim oRS
    Const adVarChar = 200
    Const adInteger = 3
    Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oRS.Fields.Append "Item", adVarChar, 255
    oRS.Fields.Append "Occurrences", adInteger, 255
    oRS.Open
    For i = LBound(pArray) To UBound(pArray)
        item = pArray(i)
        oRS.Filter = "Item='" & Replace(item, "'", "''") & "'"
        If (oRS.EOF) Then
            oRS.AddNew
            oRS.Fields("Item").Value = item
            oRS.Fields("Occurrences").Value = 1
        Else  
            oRS.Fields("Occurrences").Value = oRS.Fields("Occurrences").Value + 1
        End If
        oRS.Update
        oRS.Filter = ""
    Next
    oRS.Sort = "Occurrences DESC"
    oRS.MoveFirst
    Set CountValues_Recordset = oRS
End Function
```

And using it to achieve the output you want:

```
Dim myArray, oRS
myArray = Array("happy", "hello", "hello", "testing", "hello", "test", "hello", "happy")
Set oRS = CountValues_Recordset(myArray)
Do Until oRS.EOF
    Response.Write(oRS("item") & " " & oRS("Occurrences") & "<br />")
    oRS.MoveNext
Loop
oRS.Close
Set oRS = Nothing
```

Don't forget to close and dispose the recordset after using it.